# how to debug google AppEngine standard java8? Is there an IDE? Can I run a debugger I can set breakpoints, examine variables, etc?

Tags: google-app-engine, java-8

how to debug google AppEngine standard java8?
Is there an IDE? 
Can I run a debugger I can set breakpoints, examine variables, etc? 
If so where exactly is this documented? or a tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some documentation is here:

https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-local
https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/debugger

and for reference another stack overflow question:

[Debugging Google App Engine app in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200724/debugging-google-app-engine-app-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

Google maintains a full [list of development tools for AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/developer-and-admin-tools#development_tools_and_environments).

That list includes the following offering by google: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/google-cloud-tools-eclipse:

> Cloud Tools for Eclipse enables you to create, import, edit, build, run, debug, and deploy Java servlet applications for the App Engine standard and flexible environments without leaving Eclipse.

See the [Running and Debugging howto](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging).